# solr field replace in the query

Tags: solr, solr4

I have a query like that where "brand" is in my schema:

```
select?rows=1&start=0&sort=price+asc&q=brand:sony&qt=for-search&wt=xml
```

But I want to do this instead:

```
select?rows=1&start=0&sort=price+asc&q=brand_name:sony&qt=for-search&wt=xml
```

and define something like brand_name:brand in my Solr config. Is there a way to do that ?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use a copyField in the schema file.  You would need to create a new field called "brand_name", and give it the appropriate type.  Then add a copyField to transfer the value from "brand" to "brand_name".

```
<copyField source="brand" dest="brand_name"/>
```

Then you can reference the data in the brand_name field.

Hope that helps!

Comment: thank you, but this solution will grow my index and requires re-indexing. I was originally looking for a mapping of the field before or during the queryParser